# No selectable device in Android Studio using Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, ios-simulator

I'm using Android Studio and Flutter. I have an iOS simulator running, and flutter doctor (output below) recognizes it, but my device list only shows Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 as a greyed out option. I had no issues with different versions or anything of the like before this. It just seemingly randomly became un-selectable. Has anyone had this issue? I've looked in the **View > Tool Windows** menu, but nothing looked right. If I run `flutter run` in the terminal of Android Studio, it runs in the simulator.

**How mine looks:**

[image: AS with no devices]

**How it should look (excuse the poor quality):**

[image: AS with devices]

**flutter doctor -v**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.25.0-8.2.pre, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.25.0-8.2.pre at /Users/user/dev_tools/flutter
    • Framework revision b0a2299859 (13 days ago), 2021-01-05 12:34:13 -0800
    • Engine revision 92ae191c17
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-133.2.beta)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • AE85AE12-714C-436A-B0B1-DAC8733FB2BE • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-3 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Note: I am on the beta channel, but I have been before and worked as expected.

I've got to be missing something dumb.

EDIT:

Adding another photo of a different Flutter project on the same machine that is working as expected:

[image: Expected results]

Answer (score 0):

homie :)

had something very similar I just deleted my device closed the application down and then reinstalled the device